# building a 3d Numpy array from a 2d numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array

So I've got a numpy array like this:

```py
a = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [2, 3, 4],
              [4, 5, 6]])
```

and I want to convert it into an array like this:

```py
[[[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3]],
 [[2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4]],
 [[4, 4, 4], [5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6]]]
```

How would you do it?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`numpy.repeat`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) on the array with one extra dimension:

```
np.repeat(a[...,None], 3, axis=2)
```

Or [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html):

```
np.tile(a[...,None], (1,1,3))
```

Output:

```
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4]],

       [[4, 4, 4],
        [5, 5, 5],
        [6, 6, 6]]])
```